# How to insert <li> element on <ul> using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am having an issue with javascript and i don't know how to solve it ... 
Actually my code is working good with jsfiddle, but when i try to insert on my HTML page ,it simply doesnt work anymore ... 
What i want to, is to add the < li> on < ul> each time i tried to hit the button named "Add" !

HTML code:

```
....
<td width="50%" valign="top">
                    <b> SUPER: </b>
                    <ul id="ul">

                    </ul>
</td>
....
<input type="submit" value="Add" onclick="add()"/>
....
```

JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                        function add(){
                            var ul = document.getElementById("ul");
                            var li = document.createElement("li");
                            li.innerHTML = "LoL";
                            ul.appendChild(li);
                    }
 </script>
```

The result with that code : it doesn't add anything on my HTML page when i try to hit the button...
Thankfully,

Comment: If it works in jsFiddle but not in your page then the code should be fine. What errors do you get on your page in the console?

Comment: Do you really have a `ul` with `id="ul"`? I imagine you want `document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0]`.

Comment: Obviously we can't tell why it doesn't work on your own site without seeing what makes it different from the code that works.

Comment: @lonesomeday Yes, on line 4.

Comment: Is the `<input type="submit">` inside a `<form>`?

Comment: Well, your code works [nice](http://jsfiddle.net/vtaQg/). Do you see javascript errors?

Comment: What's the difference between getElementById or getElementsByTagName ???? isn't the same thing ??? (obviously one had a list of nodes and other not)

Comment: @Damiii The first gets elements by id. The other gets elements by tag name.

Comment: @damii TagName refers to the type of the HTML tag, eg a "ul", "input" and so on, whereas the id refers to the id attribute you assign to it. You've assigned an id of 'ul' to a 'ul' tag.

Comment: Well, my problem was due to the " type="submit" " ... which i changed after by "button" ._. !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be oversimplifying this, but here's a thought: Your input button is a SUBMIT, so when the onClick performs, the submit happens immediately thereafter, restoring the page to its original state. The process happens so quickly the appearance is that the code did nothing.

Just change the input type to "button", eg

```
<input type="button">
```

Comment: So how am i able to solve this situation ?

Comment: @Damiii Change it to `type="button"`. Do you really want that button to submit a form? If not, don't make it a submit button

Comment: Just for the sake of the notion, change the input type to a plain "button", not a "submit".

Comment: Lol, now it is working good with the type = "button" ... So stupid part of me ._.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help. Sometimes the obvious things are the ones that bite us in the tookus :) If you're so persuaded, you might check this as the answer...